# При включении в конфиге Yii session авторизация не работает

Tags: yii

До включения session уже было отлажено и хорошо работало.
В конфиге подключаю:

```
'session' => array(
        'class' => 'CDbHttpSession',
        'connectionID' => 'db',
        'sessionTableName' => '{{sessions}}',
        'autoCreateSessionTable' => true,
        'timeout' => 36000,
        'autoStart' => true,
    ),
```

Создается таблица и сессии туда складываются, но выглядит это странно: авторизуюсь, авторизация проходит, ошибок нет, в логах все корректно, но на сайте я все еще разлогинен, то есть как будто авторизация прошла успешно.
Можете подсказать, с чем это может быть связано?

Используется Yii v1.1.15

Comment: Проблема решилась, дело было в нарушенной логике поведения контроллера, который должен был отрабатывать после логона